# Can I ask to updated a question?

Tags: discussion

Or better said, **Can I ask a question which as been already asked years ago and which the answer may, or may not, be different?**

why this question:
I just asked a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94188/how-much-of-pathfinder-still-broken-since-release) which got close. I didn't realized right away how much flame it could attract and I'm ok to leave it close until it's in a better state.
That said I started to rework it, trying to deal with the problem and I realize that the straighter way to make it more neutral is just to ask again, more or less unchanged, the same [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1/differences-between-dd-3-5-and-pathfinder) I used as reference and example to build my own.
Now I'm trying anyway to improve my old question, but I'm still dubious if it is ok to re-ask a question which may have different answer today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In general, post a bounty instead of creating a new question

If there is an existing question that is the same as yours, but is outdated, the best thing to do is to create a bounty on the old question with the following reason:

> **Current answers are outdated**
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

If that isn't an option, or it won't get you the answers you are looking for, then that probably means that your question isn't the same, and you should make it clear why it isn't.

### This particular question was closed for other reasons

The close reason wasn't that your question was a duplicate of the other (which would mean the two questions are the same), but rather that it was primarily opinion based. As some of the commenters pointed out, the question as it currently stands is basically "Is Pathfinder still worse than 3.5?", which is an invitation for opinion. Some people may share that view, others disagree with it, but none of it is really fact based. Some alternative questions that are fact-based and answerable would be:

- Has Pathfinder addressed X concerns with Y mechanic since its release?
- How is Pathfinder different between its release and 2017?
- Have there been any changes to X mechanic?
- Have developers of Pathfinder ever commented on why X mechanic is the way it is?

All of these are clearly answerable with an objective answer that doesn't involve personal opinions over how a gamer feels about Pathfinder.

The other issue with this question is that it depends on a certain link. If that link ever goes down, the question is useless because it can't be understood or answered anymore.